# Building a class of DataFrame type with an append method, can not change the instance of the class

Tags: python, pandas, class, dataframe, inheritance

I'm trying to create a class that inherit from pd.DataFrame with an self-defined append method in it.

```
class test(pd.DataFrame):
  def __init__(self,df,init_balance=1000000):
    super(test, self).__init__(df)
    test.balance=init_balance

  def appd(self):
    df1=pd.DataFrame({"A": range(4)})
    self=self.append(df1)
    return self
```

What I want is the instance of the class to be a DataFrame-like data ,and when i use the method inside of the class such as the appd method, the instance should renew itself.

```
df= pd.DataFrame() 
inst1=test(df)
inst1.appd()
```

But the thing is I can't change the `instance(inst1)` of the class, it is still a empty data, although the append method can return a dataframe with data in it if use `inst2=inst1.append()`.

[image: inst1 still empty, suppose to append some data in it]

Comment: `self` is a local variable that is useful only within your methods' scopes. Replacing `self` by whatever value won't change your *actual* object

Comment: If you *really* want to subclass `pd.DataFrame()`, take a look at these guides from pandas website itself: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/internals.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures and  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/extending.html#extending-subclassing-pandas